# Xml parsing with python multirow

Tags: python, xml, minidom

I can not parse this type of xml file:

```
<items>
  <item>
   <name>Car</name>
   <description>
      <specification>
          <color>blue</color>
      </specification>
      <specification>
          <color>yellow</color>
      </specification>
   </description>
  <item>
 <items>
```

I will like recovered all the colors separating with commas.

I am a beginner in python.

```
items = doc.getElementsByTagName("items")
for item in items:
   name = item.getAttribute("name")
   color = item.getElementByTagName("color")[0]
   print(name,color.firstChild.data)
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I will recommend [BeautifulSoup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/)

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
a='''<items>
  <item>
   <name>Car</name>
   <description>
      <specification>
          <color>blue</color>
      </specification>
      <specification>
          <color>yellow</color>
      </specification>
   </description>
  <item>
 <items>'''
color_list=[]
soup = BeautifulSoup(a, "html.parser")
for i in soup.findAll('color'):
    color_list.append(i.next_element)
print(','.join(color_list)) # blue,yellow
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you ! It works for this case, but for a bigger sample, I can't do it ..

```
<TradeMark>
   <MarkImageDetails>
      <MarkImage>
         <MarkImageFilename>FMARK0000000004393852</MarkImageFilename>
         <MarkImageFileFormat>TIFF</MarkImageFileFormat>
      </MarkImage>
   </MarkImageDetails>
   <GoodsServicesDetails>
      <GoodsServices>
         <ClassificationKindCode>Nice</ClassificationKindCode>
         <ClassDescriptionDetails>
            <ClassDescription>
               <ClassNumber>35</ClassNumber>
            </ClassDescription>
            <ClassDescription>
               <ClassNumber>41</ClassNumber>
            </ClassDescription>
            <ClassDescription>
               <ClassNumber>42</ClassNumber>
            </ClassDescription>
         </ClassDescriptionDetails>
      </GoodsServices>
   </GoodsServicesDetails>
</TradeMark>
```

I would like that with ClassNumber.